# Obtain dataUrl for image taken with camera using trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

I am having problems trying to obtain a dataUrl for an image taken with the camera using code similar to that used in the sample ['How to build a location-based hybrid mobile app with reverse geocoding'](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/05/15/how-to-build-a-location-based-hybrid-mobile-app-with-reverse-geocoding/). I'm testing the code on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.5.

The code I'm using to get the dataUrl is pretty standard javascript:

```
var toDataURL = function toDataURL(uri, callback)
{
    forge.logging.log('toDataURL...');
    forge.logging.log(uri);
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = uri;
    image.onload = function ()
    {
        forge.logging.log('toDataURL image.onload...');

        // create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = 'canvas';
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // draw image to canvas
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0,  canvas.width,  canvas.height);

        // get data url 
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        callback(dataUrl);
        forge.logging.log('...toDataURL image.onload');
    };
    forge.logging.log('...toDataURL');
};
```

The problem is that the dataUrl returned by canvas.toDataURL is always empty ('data:,'). The uri passed as a parameter is logged as:

> I/Forge   (18019): [FORGE] 'content://io.trigger.forgeb6367d6ee13011e1b9ed12313d1adcbe/file___height=640&type=image&uri=content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F44%23Intent%3Bend&width=480&name=Image'

which is returned from a call to forge.file.URL with parameter:

> D/Forge   (18019): Native call "file.URL" with task.params: {"uri":"content://media/external/images/media/45#Intent;end","name":"Image","type":"image","width":480,"height":640}

Presumably this is something to do with permissions. My question is, what do I have to do to get the code to work? Or is there an alternative approach to getting the content of a file taken with the camera? (My aim is to send the content of the photo to a web service.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a proper look at the code to try to recreate here - thanks for the snippet - but in the meantime there might be a simpler solution.

If all you need to do is display the image to the user then upload it to a web service, you can just use file.getImage, file.URL and request.ajax. Cobbled together from code [here](https://github.com/trigger-corp/Forge-Demo-Apps/blob/master/camera/src/index.html) and [here](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#notes):

```
forge.file.getImage({width: 300, height: 300}, function (file) {
  // Get a URL to the returned file object which can be used from the local webview.
  forge.file.URL(file, function (url) {
    document.getElementById('img').src = url;
  });
  forge.request.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/file_upload",
    files: [file]
  });
});
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that - it looks like it should be OK. It would be great to have the flexibility of a dataUrl though, hope there's some way to make it work!

Comment: I've done a few tests and although the code works - the file gets sent to the server correctly - the file is uploaded with its orginal resolution, and not the resolution (480x640)specified by the call to getImage. Seems to work that way for images from gallery and images taken with camera. Is this normal? Thanks.